# HTML eDM - Call to Action with multiple links

Tags: html, hyperlink, google-play, electronic-direct-mail

I'm creating a simple HTML eDM with a Google Play CTA button. I have been given a mobile tracking code that links to the App on the eDM, but the problem is that the link doesn't work on Desktop (and the client wants to keep it that way).

Is there a way to implement the CTA with 2 links (one when your on mobile and one when your on desktop) so it switches depending on what device you are on?

Otherwise I'm just going to put a small "not on mobile? Click here" link under the button.

Here is the code for the current link.

```
<a href="http://ad.apps.fm/7gK1jYamDvfBocSoCzOVc65px440Px0vtrw1ww5B54xSzSHhTNUImKmzUwCLzlXe_q08ib27TpDVnUk36NYK6U8SA8KSIuYivq80SG1HpST7DCjhtWgmtb0i7jkuF0C4" target="_blank">
<img src="images/CTA_DownloadGooglePlay.jpg" width="118" height="43" border="0" alt="Get it on Google Play" style="display:block;" />
</a>
```

Cheers,

Dan